# Basis for the Kernel of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$T(v) = Av$ represents the linear transformation $T$. Find a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}_.$

I augmented $A$ with $0$:
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}_.$

Then I computed the RREF to be: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}_.$$

I have $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$ but the row of $0$`s implies a free variable. It is not clear to me  which it is. Or is it both or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the last row of your RREF to mean:

$$ 0x_1 + 0x_2 = 0. $$

This is trivially satisfied and so adds nothing new to our knowledge. The kernel of $A$ is just the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}_.$

Comment: Good , I was also able to verify this using a MATLAB function provided by the instructor.